# How to calculate difference in hours between two time fields

Tags: google-sheets

I have two time-formatted cells and I need to calculate the difference (e.g., 2.75) in hours between the two.

```
10:30 AM   |   1:15 PM
```

Simply

```
=B1-A1
```

will not do the trick.

Comment: Setting the formatting for the cell `=B1-A1` to `Format -> Number -> Duration` worked for me! https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/how-do-i-calculate-a-time-delta-in-my-google-spreadsheets

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would use the following formula to calculate the difference in hours.

### Formula

```
=(B1-A1)*24
```

### Explained

The time difference is calculated in days. If you multiply times 24, you end up with hours. Time difference is [2 hours and 3 quarters of an hour](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10:30%20AM%20-%201:15%20PM) (165 min).

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you: **[Time Tracker formula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PYtBpZq0AKKS3V14xRNOFgPbVbLsmJwvxsnUL0I_ouA/edit?usp=sharing)** and included your own solution in `C1`.

Answer (score 12):

To **calculate the time difference in hours** between

```
10:30 AM   |   1:15 PM
```

Use the **formula**:

```
=B1-A1
```

and **format that cell** as **Duration**

```
2:45:00
```

Comment: Format => Number => Duration

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, I used the formula

`=Round((hour(A2-A1)*60 + minute(A2-A1))/60,2)`

to give me the difference in decimal hours.

Answer (score -1):

I've created this formula, it might help somebody else.

```
=iferror(if((minute(E3) - minute(D3))>=0;hour(E3)-hour(D3) + (minute(E3) - minute(D3))/60;hour(E3)-hour(D3) + 1 + (60 - minute(E3) - minute(D3))/60))
```

Comment: What's the time difference you expect?

Comment: This just gets the time in hours. I'm using it in a time-tracking sheet for billing purposes.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but what is the time difference between _10:30 AM_ and _1:15 PM_?