# Duration to seconds calculation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-cell-format

There are 3 columns in my google sheet with heading Start time (col C), End Time (col D) and time taken (col E). Column E is arrived by finding the difference between col D and col C. Now when I try to convert col E into seconds, I am not getting the required output. Pls help me in solving this query by having the correct value in column E

[Example Worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ffWXyW2WLgWHJ3U-s4FmnWS3CQWrvs_YZ90AfRUFC0U/edit#gid=1191869656)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your start and end fields to time format `(Format -> Number -> Time)` and your time difference calculation field to duration format `(Format -> Number -> Duration)`.

Once you have done that you can just add and subtract times like normal number to get the time difference. However, you will get a negative time if one event stretches past midnight. So, apply if condition and add 24 hours whenever the event stretches midnight.

```
=IF(F13-E13>0, F13-E13, F13-E13+1)
```

or you can manually prevent this condition like [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22658/209274).

> A time value is stored as a fraction in google sheet, where 1 would be exactly 24 hours. E.g. 12 o'clock midnight is 0, 6 o'clock in the morning is 0.25 12 o'clock midday is 0.5 and 18 o'clock is 0.75

To calculate the number of seconds, you can use the `Hour()`, `Minute()` and `Second()` functions on that field.

```
=(((HOUR(G14))*60+(MINUTE(G14)))*60 +SECOND(G14))
```

Here is the link to [illustration sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A6AAfIlS80zfDo4KDynIj2TMVvgOt8tretw-QDc4q7o/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks. I understand this . But my job is to find the actual difference. I do not know how i gonna convert 21 and odd hrs for one row, where one time is in Early morning 1:53 AM and other time is late night 11:38 PM.Kindly provide solution for this .  @devnepsys

Comment: @VigneshRams As I mention in the answer above, find differences of two times by Set your start and end fields to time format (Format -> Number -> Time) and your time difference calculation field to duration format (Format -> Number -> Duration).

Comment: Don't do an absolute value. That gives the wrong value

Comment: @mhoran_psprep If we select the correct column format then it will give correct value. I have also included the tested sheet in an answer.

Comment: @devnepsys.. Even in the screenshot attached, you have shown one column with 78345.What will do with that value ???? I do not want that type of calculation . i just need the actual difference between two time. even one time is before midnight and another one is early morning .. i just need the actual difference .. not the one you have highlighted in your screenshot. i also went thru the sheet u attached . it also shows the same

Comment: @devnepsys your formula gives 78000+ seconds for an event that last only a few hours.

Comment: As the main problem here is calculating the time difference when any event stretches the midnight. So I have updated with conditional code to calculate the time difference.

Comment: After some fiddling, this is *the* answer. It addresses that for time calculations you should use the proper time format, and not meddle with string interpretations as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh ok !! .If string interpretation is not the accepted one. kindly let me know better way to do this @JanDoggen.. certainly would be really helpful ..

Comment: @VigneshRams can you verify if updated answer addresses your issues. Attached sheet is also updated to illustrate the answer.

Comment: Oh thanks much @devnepsys .. now i see attached document contains the updated one which i was looking for .. thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Looking at you example spreadsheet the calculation in seconds is done with the following formula:

```
=86400*(if(D4-C4<0,1,0)+D4-C4)
```

This is the breakdown of the formula:

- time and dates in spreadsheets are floating point numbers.
- D4-C4 is subtracting the start time  from the end time.
- The if  statement is cheeking if the subtraction is negative, that means you have to add a day because the time frame crossed over midnight. Taking the absolute value doesn't work.
- 86400 is the number of seconds in a day.

looking at the row where midnight is crossed:

```
 Start time 11:38:56 PM end time 1:53:11 AM
 D4-C4 is -0.90677
 It is negative so add 1: 0.09323
 now multiply by 86400: 8055 seconds
```

looking at one where the initial subtraction is positive

```
 start time 5:52:33 AM  end time 7:29:11 AM
 D4 - C4 is 0.06711
 No need to add 1
 multiply by 86400:  5798 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks much for the explanation.. Cheers mate !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
=RIGHT(E4, 2)+MID(E4, 4, 2)*60+LEFT(E4, 2)*60*60
```

[image: 0]