# how do I get the sum of hours, from 13:30 to 13.5

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

How can I have the sum of hours and minutes? For example, I enter in A1 14:20:00 how can I have in A2 the sum that's 14.33?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate a time delta in my Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/how-do-i-calculate-a-time-delta-in-my-google-spreadsheets)

Answer (score 0):

In A2:

`=HOUR(A1)+MINUTE(A1)/60`